# Show a different condition based on my time in a range

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get my time and if that time is in-between values in an array load something different, so if my time was 4:15 the different array would show because it is in-between 4:10 and 4:39

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$times = array(1 =>"12:00", 2 => "12:05", 3 =>"13:00", 4 => "13:05", 5 =>"14:00", 6 => "14:05", 7 =>"16:10", 8 => "16:39");
$mytime = date("Gi");
echo $mytime;

foreach ($times as $time)
{

if ($mytime >= date("Gi", strtotime($time)) && $mytime <= date("Gi", strtotime($time)))
{
$arguments = [
  'cond1',
  'cond2',
  'cond3',
  'cond4'
];
echo "<br />";
echo date("Gi", strtotime($time));
}
else
{
   $arguments = [
    'cond1',
    'cond2',
    'cond3'
      ];
      echo "<br />";
      echo date("Gi", strtotime($time));

}

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

@Usacoder,

You are comparing same time in the `if ()`, because `$time` variable is the same at each iteration of the `foreach`.

To solve this, you need to think about:

a) Figure out that you need to compare between to times, i.e. `$from_time` and `$from_time`.

b) How to get them from the array? What should be their indexes?

c) Ask yourself which loop statement is better to do that?

```php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$times = array(1 =>"12:00", 2 => "12:05", 3 =>"13:00", 4 => "13:05", 5 =>"14:00", 6 => "14:05", 7 =>"16:10", 8 => "20:39");
$mytime = date("Gi");
echo " My time: $mytime <br />" . PHP_EOL;;

for ($i = 1; $i < count($times); $i++)
{
    $from_time = date("Gi", strtotime($times[$i]));
    $to_time   = date("Gi", strtotime($times[$i + 1]));

    if ($mytime >= $from_time && $mytime <= $to_time)
    {
        echo "Is between $from_time to $to_time <br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Isn't between $from_time to $to_time <br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Usacoder, I'm glad that it does what you wanted.
Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is like:

```
$a >= $b && $a <= $b
```

... which equals:

```
$a == $b
```

To make a proper comparison you need to generate an interval with different lower and upper values.

Also, since your times aren't really bound to dates you can just do the calculations yourself:

1. Parse time strings:

   ```
   [$h, $m] = explode(':', '13:05');
   ```
2. Convert to a single unit (e.g. minutes):

   ```
   $minutes = 60 * $h + $m;
   ```
3. Compare with good old comparison operators.

Everything put together (error checking omitted for brevity and duplicate calls to `timeToMinutes()` used for clarity):

```
function timeToMinutes(string $time): int
{
    [$h, $m] = explode(':', $time);
    return 60 * $h + $m;
}

$times = [1 => '12:00', '12:05', '13:00', '13:05', '14:00', '14:05', '16:10', '16:39'];
$mytime = date('G:i');

$start = null;
foreach ($times as $time) {
    if ($start !== null) {
        $end = $time;
        if (timeToMinutes($mytime) >= timeToMinutes($start) && timeToMinutes($mytime) <= timeToMinutes($end)) {
            echo "$mytime is between $start and $end\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    $start = $time;
}
```